# Enqueueing a message to Azure Storage in an Azure function without changing the output

Tags: azure, go, azure-functions

I have a custom handler written in Go running as an Azure Function. It has an endpoint with two methods:

- POST /entities
- PUT  /entities

It was easy to make my application run as an Azure function: I added `"enableForwardingHttpRequest": true` to `host.json`, and it just works.

**What I need to achieve:** life happened and now I need to enqueue a message when my entities change, so it will trigger another function that uses a `queueTrigger` to perform some async stuff.

**What I tried:** The only way I found so far was to disable `enableForwardingHttpRequest`, and change all my endpoints to accept the Azure Function's raw JSON input and output, and then output a message in one of the fields (as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers#response-payload).

It sounds like a huge change to perform something simple... Is there a way I can enqueue a message without having to change all the way my application handles requests?

Comment: You can refer to open GitHub issue: [golang customHandler HTTP redirect not sent back to client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7318) , wait for other community members' response or open a new issue on [azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host)

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7318) document as of now custom handlers related to go lang in Azure functions having a bug and which need to be fixed.
[image]

Comment: Hey @Esdras Beleza, has it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: If the posted answer justifies your requirement, you may [mark it as the answer] by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. Doing so can benefit other community members